# How to define a function by intervals in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

How can I define a function f(x) in Mathematica that gives 1 if x is in [-5, -4] or [1, 3] and 0 otherwise? It's probably something simple but I just can't figure it out!

Comment: If statements work just fine, moreover, in an If statement,  one can define only those piecewise variable ranges that are defined for a function, such that for plotting and other conditions no superfluous range definitions are needed.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The basic construction you want is [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Piecewise.html), in particular the function you were asking for can be written as

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{1, -5 <= x <= -3}, {1, 1 <= x <= 3}}, 0]
```

or

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{1, -5 <= x <= -3 || 1 <= x <= 3}}, 0]
```

Note that the final argument, `0` defines the default (or "else") value is not needed because the default default is 0.

Also note that although [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Piecewise.html) and [`Which`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Which.html) are very similar in form, `Piecewise` is for constructing functions, while `Which` is for programming. `Piecewise` will play nicer with integration, simplification etc..., it also has the proper left-brace mathematical notation, see the examples in the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Piecewise.html).

---

Since the piecewise function you want is quite simple, it could also be constructed from step functions like [`Boole`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Boole.html), [`UnitStep`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/UnitStep.html) and [`UnitBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/UnitBox.html), e.g.

```
UnitBox[(x + 4)/2] + UnitBox[(x - 2)/2]
```

These are just special cases of `Piecewise`, as shown by `PiecewiseExpand`

```
In[19]:= f[x] == UnitBox[(x+4)/2] + UnitBox[(x-2)/2]//PiecewiseExpand//Simplify
Out[19]= True
```

---

Alternatively, you can use switching functions like [`HeavisideTheta`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HeavisideTheta.html) or [`HeavisidePi`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HeavisidePi.html), e.g.

```
HeavisidePi[(x + 4)/2] + HeavisidePi[(x - 2)/2]
```

which are nice, because if treating the function as a distribution, then its derivative will return the correct combination of [Dirac delta](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DiracDelta.html) functions.

---

For more discussion see the tutorial [Piecewise Functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/PiecewiseFunctions.html).

Comment: I'm not sure if etiquette here allows replying just to say "thanks" but I'll do that. :) The depth of Mathematica (and your knowledge of it) is overwhelming.

Comment: @yahelc: Thanks for that final 10pts! (You'd think that powers of 2 would be more important on a programmers site than powers of 10...)

Answer (score 13):

Although Simon's answer is the canonical and correct one, here are another two options:

```
f[x_] := 1 /; IntervalMemberQ[Interval[{-5, -3}, {1, 3}], x]
f[x_?NumericQ] := 0
```

or

```
f[x_] := If[-5 <= x <= -3 || 1 <= x <= 3, 1, 0]
```

---

Edit:
Note that the first option depends on the order that the definitions were entered (thanks Sjoerd for pointing this out). A similar solution that does not have this problem and will also work correctly when supplied an `Interval` as input is

```
f[x_] := 0 /; !IntervalMemberQ[Interval[{-5, -3}, {1, 3}], x]
f[x_] := 1 /;  IntervalMemberQ[Interval[{-5, -3}, {1, 3}], x]
```

Comment: +1 for [IntervalMemberQ](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/IntervalMemberQ.html). I never seem to use the [Interval](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Interval.html) arithmetic in Mathematica...

Comment: Another issue with the first example is that it's not equivalent to the `If[...]` version or the `Piecewise` one. For regions not within the `Interval`, `f[x]` is undefined.

Comment: @belisarius: Made a couple of small changes - hope that's ok.

Comment: @belisarius: But the `Piecewise` function remains unevaluated for symbolic arguments - your `f[x_]:=0` did not...

Comment: @belisarius: Ah... told you I haven't used intervals much, I didn't think of this problem. There should be a built in predicate for `NumericalIntervalQ` that includes the degenerate case of `NumericQ`...

Comment: @simon I don't think your edit is correct. Without the ?NumericQ pattern the first definition was more general than the second one causing the second one to be tried first during evaluation. With the addition of ?NumericQ this order is now changed and as far as I can see mma now executes the first one for every numeric argument returning 0 regardless of whether the number is in the interval or not.

Comment: @Sjoerd: Ouch! You're right. Mma can't decide which definition is more general, so it keeps them in the order that they were entered. Reverse the order, like it must have been in my test code, and it works!

Comment: @belisarius: By the way, sorry for making a mess of your answer. From now on, I'll try to resist the urge of thinking that I know better!

Comment: @Simon I always thought knowledge is created iff: 1) we have enough self-confidence to be able to think that we can come up with a better solution to a problem and 2) we have enough humility to accept that we could be wrong. As far as those two conditions are met, you will always find me supporting the proposal of a new idea. As for the methodology (editing somebody's else answer), it is what the mechanics of the site allows, so don't mind about it. Of course a friendly discussion by a blackboard could be better, but that again would surely seemed harsh if suggested in Aristotle's Academia.

Answer (score 0):

All is good and well but as a general rule of the thumb one should try always the simplest approach and keep away as possible from the sophisticated high level programming. In this particular situation I mean the following:

f[x_ /; -5 <= x <= -3] = 0 etc ... etc